# How to add part to table of contents in beamer?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I want to add the document part details to the table of contents and make them shadowed while navigating frames.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\mypart}{
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
    \partpage
\end{frame}
}

\newcommand{\mymaintoc}{
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
    \frametitle{Outline}
        \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
}

\newcommand{\mytoc}{
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[
        sectionstyle=show/shaded,
        subsectionstyle=show/shaded,
        subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded
    ]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
    \mymaintoc
    \section{Introduction}
    \begin{frame}{Intro}
    \end{frame}

    \part{Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone}
    \mypart
    \section{Section 1}
    \mytoc
    \frame{}

    \part{Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets}
    \mypart
    \section{Section 2}
    \mytoc
    \frame{}
    \section{Section 3}
    \mytoc
    \frame{}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to trying to obtain the following:

- Introduction
- Part I: Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone

  - Section 1
- Part II: Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets

  - Section 2
  - Section 3

Moreover, I would like to shade the parts and sections in `\mytoc`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginPart{
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
    \partpage
\end{frame}
}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{part}



\newcommand{\mymaintoc}{
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
    \addtobeamertemplate{section in toc}{\hspace{0.5cm}}{}
    \foreach\x in {1,...,\totvalue{part}}{%
    
        \vfill
        \vskip-0.4cm
        Part \x: \nameref{part:\x}
        \vfill
        
        \tableofcontents[part=\x]%
    }%
    \end{frame}
}

\newcommand{\mytoc}{
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[
        sectionstyle=show/shaded,
        subsectionstyle=show/shaded,
        subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded
    ]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
    \mymaintoc
    \section{Introduction}
    \begin{frame}{Intro}
    \end{frame}

    \part{Foo}
    \makeatletter
    \expandafter\NR@gettitle\expandafter{\beamer@partname}
    \makeatother
    \label{part:1}
    \section{Section 1}
    \mytoc
    \frame{}

    \part{Bar}
    \makeatletter
    \expandafter\NR@gettitle\expandafter{\beamer@partname}
    \makeatother
    \label{part:2}
    \section{Section 2}
    \mytoc
    \frame{}
    \section{Section 3}
    \mytoc
    \frame{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With beamer v3.70 or newer, the above code can be simplified to

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginPart{
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
    \partpage
\end{frame}
\label{part:\thepart}
}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{part}



\newcommand{\mymaintoc}{
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
    \addtobeamertemplate{section in toc}{\hspace{0.5cm}}{}
    \foreach\x in {1,...,\totvalue{part}}{%
    
        \vfill
        \vskip-0.4cm
        Part \x: \nameref{part:\x}
        \vfill
        
        \tableofcontents[part=\x]%
    }%
    \end{frame}
}

\newcommand{\mytoc}{
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[
        sectionstyle=show/shaded,
        subsectionstyle=show/shaded,
        subsubsectionstyle=show/shaded
    ]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
    \mymaintoc
    \section{Introduction}
    \begin{frame}{Intro}
    \end{frame}

    \part{Foo}

    \section{Section 1}
    \mytoc
    \frame{}

    \part{Bar}

    \section{Section 2}
    \mytoc
    \frame{}
    \section{Section 3}
    \mytoc
    \frame{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to go about adding inactive parts and sections in \mytoc? Example: \mytoc in Section 3 showing the shaded Introduction, Section 1, and Section 2.

Comment: @untitled That's an unrelated question. Please don't ask more than one question per post.

Comment: Thank you for your countless contributions. The post may have been mistitled. But the description asks for making inactive parts and sections shaded.